# Celltypes in FastExel: writing data

Tags: java, fast-excel

I'm writing data to a spreadsheet using FastExcel/Java using the overloaded method

```
worksheet.value(rowIndex, columnIndex, value);
```

One would expect the celltype is determined by the type of the value.
Unfortunately this is not the case. All celltypes are 'Standard.'
This results in displaying a date as its numerical value and strings consisting of decimals **with** leading zeros as strings **without** leading zeros.
In poi the value sets the celltype. Somehow this is not the case in FastExcel.
What am I missing? Can I explicitly set the celltype?